# Scope to filter Teams depending on memeber's age

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `User` with an attribute `:age` and a model `Team` that `has_many: :users`.

I would like to know, how I could create 2 scopes `:same_ages` and `:different_ages` to filter teams, either if they all have the same age, or if they have different ages.

```
Team.same_ages
# In all teams returned, all members have the same age

Team.different_ages
# In all teams returned, there is at least one member with
# different age as the others
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just think the scopes will be like:

```
scope :same_ages, -> {
   where("id IN (SELECT team_id
                 FROM users
                 GROUP BY team_id 
                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(age)) = 1)"
}

scope :different_ages, -> {
   where("id IN (SELECT team_id
                 FROM users
                 GROUP BY team_id 
                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(age)) > 1)"
}
```